Roblox RemoveEvent Firing 2 times for some odd reason
I'm making a Roblox code executor that is server sided but everytime I put in code like "print('Hello World!')" it runs that code two times for some reason.
Here is the Client Code:
local textbox = script.Parent
local Attempts = 0
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.FireCode
local Debounce = false

textbox.FocusLost:Connect(function(enterPressed)
    if enterPressed == true and Debounce ~= true then
        Debounce = true
        repeat
            Attempts += 1
            print(Attempts)
            event:FireServer(textbox.Text)
            task.wait()
        until Attempts == 1
        task.wait(1)
        Attempts = 0
    else
        return
    end
    Debounce = false
end)

Here is the Server Code:
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.FireCode
local debounce = false

event.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, code)
    if player and player ~= nil and debounce ~= true then
        debounce = true
        loadstring(tostring(code))()
        task.wait(0.1)
        debounce = false
    end
end)

There are no errors with the code.
I tried using the debounce method but it didn't work.

Not sure why you are calling the event inside a loop, even if that loop should only execute once. Here's how I would approach a debounced event handler.
It might be worth searching your Workspace when the game is running to see if you somehow have clones of this LocalScript somewhere.
local textbox = script.Parent
local event = game.ReplicatedStorage.FireCode
local debounce = false
local COOLDOWN = 2.0 -- seconds

textbox.FocusLost:Connect(function(enterPressed)
    -- escape if the flag is active
    if debounce then
       return
    end
    
    if enterPressed then
        debounce = true
        -- get the code and then clear the text box so we don't repeat the same command
        local code = textbox.Text
        textbox.Text = ""

        -- execute the code
        event:FireServer(code)

        -- wait for a moment before clearing the debounce flag
        wait(COOLDOWN)
        debounce = false
    end
end)

